# JavaScript: Is it possible to declare a variable using another variable's value?

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-declaration, variable-initialization

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
const a = 'name';
const ${a} = 1;
```

The second variable should be:

`const name = 1;`

Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, you can not.

Answer (score 2):

Could use an object though, something like

```
var obj;
var x = "name";
obj[x] = 1;

console.log(obj[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = 'name';
eval (a + " = 37");
```

This will create a variable `name` with the value `37`.

However, I prefer Nobel Eugene's solution as a better approach to the problem.